# Using Python for FFTs on audio files - sampling rate

Tags: python, audio, numpy

I've been trying to find some frequencies that are most dominant in a WAV file. I've found out that I can use the python `wave` library, as well as `scipy.io.wavfile` for reading the audio file.

If the sampling rate is 16000, does that mean my timestep is 1/16000? That means my code should look something like this for finding the frequencies:

```
wavData = wavfile.read(someName); # 2D array of sampling rate and values
fourier = fftpack.fft(wavData[0][1]); # FFT on the values
n = wavData[0][1].size;
timestep = 1/wavData[0]; # 1/16000
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep); # getting array of sample frequencies
```

I'm following the documentation from scipy.org using examples for [`fftfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq) and [`fft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft).

Comment: Yes.  16Khz sample rate means each sample is 1/16000'th of a second = 62.5uS

Comment: Thank you! That helped quite a lot. I realized that when I sampled from my WAV file, I don't think I am receiving the decibel value. Is there a way for me to so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the sampling rate is 16000, does that mean my timestep is 1/16000?

Yes, that's correct; 16,000 samples per second means that each covers 1/16,000 of a second. However, note that in Python 2.x you will need to explicitly use `float`s to get the correct `timestep`:

```
timestep = 1.0 / wavData[0]
```

As, using 2.x's default integer division:

```
1 / 16000 == 0
```

Whereas

```
1.0 / 16000 == 6.25e-05
```